# Combining image and text within a button in kivy

Tags: kivy

What's the preferred way to combine an image/icon and text within a button? For example, how would you create a button with `text = 'my button'`, and a graphical icon to the left of that text?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regarding to question #2.

The way Kivy works is embedding `Widget` instances. Since `Image` and `Button` are subclasses of Widget, then all you have to do is embed an Image inside a the Button. Notice that the positioning inside a widget is fixed. You have to give explicit coordinates.

That said, you can always embed a `Layout` to organize the stuff you are putting inside the Button.

Here is the simple ex

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<ButtonsApp>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "B1"
        Image:
            source: 'kivy.png'
            y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 200
            x: self.parent.x
    Label:
        text: "A label"
""")

class ButtonsApp(App, BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonsApp().run()
```

**EDIT: An example of how a relative layout can be embedded inside a button**

In this case I am using a `StackLayout` to organize an `Image` and a `Label` inside. As I said, `Button` is a `Widget` and Kivy works embedding widgets inside widgets. It doesn't matter if they are labels, buttons or layouts.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<ButtonsApp>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        StackLayout:
            pos: self.parent.pos
            size: self.parent.size
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            Image:
                source: 'kivy.png'
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 74
            Label:
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 100
                text: "The text"
    Label:
        text: "A label"
""")

class ButtonsApp(App, BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonsApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, tico. However, the assigning of the image's position relative to the parent seems to raise an issue. Let's say the text of your button is dynamically generated (i.e. of variable length), and you want the image to always appear the width of 10 pixels to the left of the text - to determine image position, do you have to write a function that takes as input the number of characters in the button's text, and determines the x value accordingly?

Comment: In that case you add a `Label` and `Image` inside another `Layout`. I would say a `BoxLayout` and `orientation: horizontal`. I guess it is easier to provide you with another example.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, there is another way.
You can use icon fonts such as Font Awesome and combine them with text.

Either import the font directly and wrap the text in their font tag, or simply use some of the libraries that take care of that.

```py
#: import icon ...
Button:
    markup: True
    text: "%s Comment" % icon('comment', 32)
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 100
```

[Kivy-iconfonts](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.iconfonts) converts css/tff combinations that are distributed for web sites into a json format that it loads during runtime using the import statement as shown in the example above.
I extended this in [my fork](https://pypi.org/project/kivysome/) to fetch Font Awesome icons during runtime and put them into the working directory of your application. That gives you the advantage of not having to distribute the fonts with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new Button class or modify the one in Kivy.uix.button

```
class MyButton(Button):
    #add these three properties in the class
    icon = ObjectProperty(None)
    icon_size = (0,0)
    icon_padding = NumericProperty(0)    #Enter any default value like 50 if you will
                                         #always use an icon, or specify this field
                                         #while creating the button
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #no changes here, just for reference
        return super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

KV file:

```
<MyButton>:
state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: self.background_color
    BorderImage:
        border: self.border
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image

    Color:
        rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1) if root.icon != None else (1,1,1,0)

    Rectangle:
        source: root.icon
        size: (self.texture_size[1],self.texture_size[1]) if self.icon_size == (0,0) else self.icon_size
        pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.)-dp(root.icon_padding), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)

    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

    Rectangle:
        texture: self.texture
        size: self.texture_size
        pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.)+dp(root.icon_padding), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
```

Now just create a button widget

```
MyButton(text = 'Hello',icon = 'icon.png', icon_padding = 50)
```