# ScrollView and CustomButton

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I woud like to create ScrollView with custom Buttons (Label + Image), but I've got problem with proper positioning Label and Image on Button object.

Code:

```
class TestScreen(Screen):
    def change(self, btn, pos):
        print pos
    def populate(self):
        scroll = self.ids.myscroll
        grid = self.ids.scrollgrid
        btn =  Button(size_hint_y=None, width='29sp', text='')
        box = BoxLayout(size=btn.size, pos=btn.pos,orientation='horizontal')
        image = Image(source='image.png', size_hint_x=None, width=74)
        label = Label(size_hint_x=None, width=100, text='test')

        box.add_widget(image)
        box.add_widget(label)

        btn.add_widget(box)
        grid.add_widget(btn)

        btn.bind(pos=partial(self.change))
```

and .kv file:

```
<TestScreen>:
   Button:
       text: 'populate'
       size_hint: None, None
       size: 100,100
       pos: 0,0
       on_press: root.populate()
   ScrollView:
       id: myscroll
       size_hint: None, None
       size: 300, 500
       pos: 100, 100
       scroll_x: 0.5
       GridLayout:
          spacing: 20
          padding: 20
          id: scrollgrid
          size_hint: None, None
          cols: 1
           size_hint_y:  None
       children
        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.parent.width
```

The biggest problem is that during creating BoxLayout in populate(), btn.pos is [0,0] and after rendering btn.pos is changed to proper coordinates (I checked that using bind() for pos). How can I get correct cooridnates during creating mentioned BoxLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a widget to another widget, which isn't a layout, it will receive default pos (0,0) and size (100, 100). Use a grid layout to pack an image and a button together. Example:

*main.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from random import choice


class ImageButton(GridLayout):

    images = [
        'http://kivy.org/logos/kivy-logo-black-256.png',
        'http://img.interia.pl/rozrywka/nimg/2/7/roz4286600.jpg',
        'http://www.i-programmer.info/images/stories/News/2014/Apr/A/kivycont2.jpg',
        'http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/9/90155/2472244-abathur.png',
        'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a07de5a89d18964a22775deae84d9ba6?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG',
        'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/578e323e1c4dda99b24bf047e0cb2e3e?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'
    ]

    source = StringProperty(images[0])

    def change_image(self):
        while True:
            new_img = choice(self.images)
            if new_img != self.source:
                self.source = new_img
                break


class MainScreen(Screen):

    grid = ObjectProperty()

    def populate(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            self.grid.add_widget(ImageButton())


class Test(App):

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.populate()


Test().run()
```

*test.kv:*

```
MainScreen:
    grid: grid

    ScrollView:

        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 1
            spacing: '10dp'
            padding: '10dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height


<ImageButton>:
    cols: 2
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '200dp'

    AsyncImage:
        source: root.source
        size_hint_x: 0.3

    Button:
        text: 'click me'
        on_press: root.change_image()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding widgets to a `Button` isn't a very nice solution. Button actually is a `Label` with a behavior set to it, therefore you only duplicate it without any good reason. How to make such a widget(a button with an image) is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982801/combining-image-and-text-within-a-button-in-kivy), you'd need only to choose a position for `Image` and position whole widget for your needs. In the first example the `App` class also behaves as a `BoxLayout`, so imagine it as a layout only - a root widget. From there it'll be easy.

Also, when a widget is initialized, it comes with the default values of `size` and `pos` and other values specific for the widget itself, which are then changed. Basically, you created a widget with `btn = Button()`, but didn't set any `pos` or `size`, so when you access the position later within `box`, you only take the defaults and well... place them to `size` and `pos` of another widget - so you only replaced defaults with the same values. To get correct values you'll need to set them first inside the widget to your desired pos&size.